# Java logic error that doesn't always exist

Tags: java, logic

I'm still fairly new to Java, but I'm fairly sure this shouldn't happen. There's some sort of bizarre logic error in my paintComponent method, which is preventing images from being drawn properly. Normally this wouldn't be an issue, and I could find a way around it. However, the problem doesn't always exist. Commenting and decommenting one line at a time will sometimes get around it, as will closing and reopening the IDE. (Eclipse.) What could possibly cause this, and what can be done to avoid it?

Here's my method:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    g.drawImage(titlebg, 0, 0, null);
    g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    g.fillRect(300, 250, 300, 50);
    //g.fillRect(400, 400, 300, 50);
    g.drawImage(ccground, 0, 0, null);
}
```

EDIT: The drawImage methods are not functioning when the setColor and fillRect methods are uncommented. Sometimes they don't work even if it's just the two of them. Sometimes they do.

EDIT 2: The only other call to the images is in the following code, which initializes them.

```
Toolkit tk = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();

public Image retrieveImage(String x){
    URL y = this.getClass().getResource(x);
    Image img = tk.getImage(y);
    return img;
}
```

This is referenced with:

```
public void loadImages(){
    ccground = rl.retrieveImage("\\Chrysaline Caverns ground tile.png");
    titlebg = rl.retrieveImage("\\Title Screen.png");
}
```

in the same class as the paintComponent method.

EDIT 3: Stacktrace.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.awt.Container.addImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.JFrame.addImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Container.add(Unknown Source)
at gui.Main.createGui(Main.java:32)
at gui.Main$1.run(Main.java:21)
at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Main.class

```
public class Main extends JFrame{
static Window w;
JFrame f;
Image ccground;
Main(){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            createGui();
        }
    });

}
public static void main(String[] args){
    w = new Window();
}
public void createGui(){
    JFrame f = new JFrame();
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.add(w);
    f.pack();
    f.setVisible(true);
    f.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
}
}
```

EDIT 4: Window.java

```
public class Window extends JPanel{
Main m;
ResourceLoader rl;
Image ccground;
Image titlebg;
public Window(){
    rl = new ResourceLoader();
    m = new Main();
    loadImages();
}
public Dimension getPreferredSize(){
    return new Dimension(800, 592);
}
public void loadImages(){
    ccground = rl.retrieveImage("\\Chrysaline Caverns ground tile.png");
    titlebg = rl.retrieveImage("\\Title Screen.png");
}
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    g.drawImage(titlebg, 0, 0, null);
    g.setColor(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
    g.fillRect(300, 250, 300, 50);
    //g.fillRect(400, 400, 300, 50);
    g.drawImage(ccground, 0, 0, null);
}
}
```

Comment: Posting a [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers.

Comment: You never explain what the problem is...

Comment: A common cause of strange/random display problems is attempting to update GUI components using threads other than the GUI Event Thread.

Comment: Specify in detail what erroneous behavior you are observing.

Comment: Sometimes the images appear in the frame, and sometimes they don't. Occasionally, commenting and uncommenting lines fixes things. There doesn't seem to be any pattern to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(url) is the culprit. The method *gets* you an image that is not necessarily loaded yet (an empty dummy in a way).
Since you don't do anything to ensure the image is loaded, it sometimes is and sometimes it isn't.

*One* of many ways to ensure the image is completely loaded before using it is (shortest one I know of) to excute this for each image obtained from Toolkit before using it:

new ImageIcon(image).getImage();

---

EDIT:

Alter you retrieveImage like this and it should work OR clearly indicate the image was not found:

```
public Image retrieveImage(String x){
    URL y = this.getClass().getResource(x);
    Image img = tk.getImage(y);
    if (img == null)
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("image " + x + " not found");
    return new ImageIcon(img).getImage();
}
```

Comment: I presume that line would be placed after the initialization of URL y, correct? Placing it anywhere in that method creates a NullPointerException somehow. What might be causing this?

Comment: You use it with the image you obtained from the Toolkit. The ImageIcon constructor ensures the Toolkit image is fully loaded to memory. If you get an NPE you did not get an image from the Toolkit Your code does not check if you actually GOT anything from Toolkit.getImage(url). The constructor does not accept null.

Comment: A common problem when using Eclipse is that if you alter your source directory tree from outside eclipse (shell, cmd, explorere etc.), Eclipse will not recognize the changes until you 'Refresh' the modified package (Context menu / F5). An image added to the source will not be accessible when running the project until you did this.

Comment: How would I check that the image is constructed? Slotting in new ImageIcon(img).getImage(); in the retrieveImage method causes an NPE, as does placing a similar line elsewhere in the code. What should I do to ensure that the image is loaded?

EDIT: The directory tree isn't the issue-- sometimes the images WILL load, so I know that Eclipse can recognize them.

Comment: Tackle the problem systematically. First find out if the images are not loaded sometimes or something else happens. An NPE indicates you did not check for an error condition where you should have. See edit of the answer on how to find out.

Comment: Upon making the changes you suggested, I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: And that 'same error' is what exactly? Nobody can (and wants to) help you if you keep the exact nature of the error obscure. If its an Exception, post the (entire) stacktrace.

Comment: Oh, okay. My apologies. Will update question with stacktrace and relevant blocks.

Comment: Look at your stacktrace. The error lies obviously in creating the UI, that before even anything is painted. Your main class is (honestly) a mess. From what I can see you create the GUI elements in a completely chaotic order, and at least three times as many as needed. You should not inherit your main class from JFrame - you create your own JFrame in createGUI. What is Window for? The main class you posted can *not* produce *that* stacktrace. It's not even compiling, since the Window() constructor is private.

Comment: I realize that the trace indicates an error in UI initialization. However, I haven't even touched anything except the methods I had previously mentioned since it was working. At your advice, I've stopped it extending JFrame. (You're right, that was kind of pointless.) I'm not sure what you mean when you say that the Window constructor is private. I'll post the Window class as well. It initializes Main and ResourceLoader, and contains the paintComponent method. It extends JPanel.

Comment: Ah, I see. I assumed Window specified the class java.awt.Window (BTW its a good idea to avoid giving your classes the same names as classes in the JDK). From what I see you created a race condition in the initialization - you declare 'static Window w' in class Main, and your Window constructor creates Main, which in turn calls createGUI. This is bad, very bad. There is no guarantee Main.w has been initialized at the time createGUI()'s invokeLater is executed (its timing dependent). It crashes when loadImages() takes enough time so the Window constructor has not exited when invoke executes.

Comment: You should not declare Main.w static, and you should create *all* GUI components from the same place, notably the createGUI() method. Main's main method should not create the JPanel (Window), thats part of the GUI. So main should just invoke createGUI(), and all the GUI components should be create there. That avoids the timing problems and also freak threading problems that can happen with Swing if you access components from a thread other than the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread). Its a hurdle most, if not all beginners stumble over at least once, so don't feel too bad about making a mistake.

Comment: Thank you so much-- I followed what you said to do here, and it works now. Hopefully I won't fall prey to this again.